# Prime factorizations of consecutive numbers, can they both contains powers of greater than or equal to $1000$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Say that a positive integer n is highly exponential if there is an exponent greater than or equal to 1000 in its prime factorization. Can there exist two such numbers consecutively?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: what are the size of these factors, what is required to balance out their difference.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Not sure what is meant by that.

Comment: Well all I know for certain is that if m,n are consecutive numbers then they are relatively prime (so all the primes in their prime factorization are unique) and m - n = 1.

Comment: $2^{1000}$ is 302 digits, $3^{1000}$ is 478 digits,$5^{1000}$ ups it to 699 digits.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That doesn't really help though. It is conceivable that a large constant times $2^{1000}$ is of the same order of magnitude as $3^{1000}$, for example.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee yes but isn't it possible to have other distinct primes in their factorization which could make up this difference?

Comment: I was asking the OP to think about that @YiFan

Comment: Powers of . . .? Looks like your title is missing a word after "of".

Answer (score 6):

You're essentially asking for positive integer solutions to the Diophantine equation
$$ax^{1000}-by^{1000}=1,$$
for $x,y\neq 1$. The answer is that there is certainly a solution. To see why, recall Bezout's identity:

> **Bezout's identity.** Given any coprime integers $a,b$, there exist integers $x,y$ so that $ax+by=1$.

So if we were to choose $y=x+1$, then certainly $x^{1000}$ and $y^{1000}$ would be coprime, so there must be integers $a,b$ that satisfy the equation. Of course, don't expect to be able to find an explicit example, since the order of magnitude of the quantities involved are so large.

Comment: Oh...true, the numbers are large, but the Euclidean Algorithm is amazingly effective.  [Here's](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Bezout%282%5E1000%2C3%5E1000%29) the result for $2^{1000},3^{1000}$.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think to look at it like this! Thank you so much for the help!